# Interaction of python with pypy via subprocess

Tags: python, io, subprocess, nonblocking, output-buffering

I'm writing a pygtk application in Python 2.7.5 that requires some heavy mathematical calculations, so I need to do these calculations in an external pypy (that don't support gtk) for efficiency and plot the results in the main program as they are produced.

Since the ouput of the calculations is potentially infinite and I want to show it as it is produced, I cannot use `subprocess.Popen.communicate(input)`.

I am able to do non-blocking reads of the output (via `fcntl`), but I am not able to effectively send the input (or anyway something else that I don't see is going wrong). For ex, the following code:

```
import subprocess

# start pypy subprocess
pypy = subprocess.Popen(['pypy', '-u'], bufsize=0, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

# send input to pypy
pypy.stdin.write('import sys\nprint "hello"\nsys.stdout.flush()\n')
pypy.stdin.flush()

# read output from pypy
pypy.stdout.flush()
print pypy.stdout.readline()
```

Will get stuck on the last line. What is weird to me is that if I substitute `'pypy'` with `'cat'` it will work, and if I substitute the input-output lines with

```
print pypy.communicate(input='import sys\nprint "hello"\nsys.stdout.flush()\n')[0]
```

it will also work (but it does not fit with what I want to do). I thought it was a problem of buffering, but I tried several ways of avoiding it (including writing to stderr and so) with no luck. I also tried sending to pypy the command to print in a `while True` loop, also with no luck (that makes me think that is not a problem with output buffering but maybe with input buffering).

Comment: You may want to communicate through a dedicated pipe (or socket for windows compatibility) and either use `select` to check for availability or explicitly read with a timeout. In this case, does removing `pypy.stdout.flush()` help? How about read() instead of readline()?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! It does not help, i tried to do non-blocking reads (timeout=0) but it just keeps not reading anything forever (and I tried every possible combination of flushing and not flushing with no effect).

I really think that the problem is that the input is not sent, since I tried to send intensive code that should lead to increased CPU usage but it didn't.

Comment: my guess is that python REPL reads from terminal directly outside of stdin. Try script that explicitly reads from stdin e.g., `['ipython', 'console']`. See how `ipython notebook` works (sockets)